# How to get the next line with TextPointer.GetLineStartPosition() in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to get the lines of the `RichTextBox`.

Here they show how to do it:
[Using GetLineStartPosition to get the end of a line in WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060108/using-getlinestartposition-to-get-the-end-of-a-line-in-wpf-richtextbox)

But for whatever reason I always get `null` as the return of `GetLineStartPosition(1)`.

XAML

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40" Click="Button_Click"></Button>

            <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbEditor">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph>Hello, world!
                        a
                        <LineBreak/>
                        b
                        <LineBreak/>
                        c
                        <LineBreak/>
                        d
                    </Paragraph>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r\n");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r\n");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\r\n");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\n");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\n");
            rtbEditor.AppendText("testtext" + "\n");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextPointer contentStart = rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart;
            var nextStart = contentStart.GetLineStartPosition(1);
        }
```

`nextStart` is `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if `GetLineStartPosition(...)` returns null that means you are stand on the last line this method works relatively with the previous Pointer, try use `rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart.GetLineStartPosition(0)` than get the X-th line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took a bit of research into how `FlowDocument`s and `TextPointer`s worked. I'd suggest reading the [TextPointer Remarks Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textpointer#remarks) because it really helped me understand this.

My theory is that the `GetLineStartPosition` method won't work if the current `TextPointer` doesn't have a [`Paragraph`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textpointer.paragraph) to reference. `Document.ContentStart` gives you a `TextPointer` that's just before the first `Paragraph` in the `FlowDocument`. You can call `GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)` to return a `TextPointer` to the next valid insertion point- in this case the *first* valid insertion point- in the document. From there you are inside the first `Paragraph` and `GetLineStartPosition` starts to work.

```
TextPointer contentStart = rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
var nextStart = contentStart.GetLineStartPosition(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. That is really counterintuitive especially since it is not mentioned in GetLineStartPosition() documentation